# Jest Unit test case for React functional component Api call

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-typescript

I am new to Jest Unit testing. I need to write a test case for a React functional Component. Below is the code snippet for API call

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getInitialData(props.id, props.baseUrl).then((response: any) => {
      setInitialResponse(response.initialResponse);
      if (props.initialData) props.initialData(response.initialResponse);
      setLoader(false);
    });
  }, []);
```

I don't know how to cover these lines in the jest test case. Passing id and baseUrl to this component, not covering lines after 'then'. I don't know How can I mock this also as it is present inside `useEffect`.

Comment: please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Share the snippet you have tried so far.

Comment: are you using enzyme or react testing library?

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I use the jest to test something after the API has finished fetching.

Create Mock Function, (May be in other file to be used by all test cases, change it the way you want to setup)

```
const mockAPI = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('foo');
  }, 300);
});
```

Define APIs

```
 import * as APIS from '~/api/[API_PATH]';

  const mockGetInitialData = (params = {}) =>
    jest
      .spyOn(APIS, 'getInitialData')
      .mockImplementation(() => mockAPI(params));
```

Test case

```
it('Initial Data loading Failed', async () => {
    mockGetInitialData({
      error: { errors: {name: 'Invalid Name' } }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you import the `getInitialData` function from somewhere, a mock for that would look like this

```
  jest.mock("./getInitialData", () =>
    jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(initialResponseMock)
  );
  // rest of your test in here
```

The concept you are missing is that you need to use `mockResolvedValue` when mocking async code.

https://blog.jimmydc.com/mock-asynchronous-functions-with-jest/